# A way to make a time intersection in nested queries

Tags: jquery

I have this code that fades in and out several DIVs one after another:

```
$('div#faderhome').fadeIn(500, function() {
 $('div#faderhome').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {
  $('div#faderbranding').fadeIn(500, function() {
   $('div#faderbranding').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {
    $('div#faderbusiness').fadeIn(500, function() {
     $('div#faderbusiness').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {
      $('div#fadercontact').fadeIn(500, function() {
       $('div#fadercontact').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {
        $('div#fadermarketing').fadeIn(500, function() {
         $('div#fadermarketing').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {
          $('div#faderprofile').fadeIn(500, function() {
           $('div#faderprofile').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {
            $('div#fadersoftware').fadeIn(500, function() {
             $('div#fadersoftware').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {
              $('div#faderidentity').fadeIn(500, function() {
               $('div#faderidentity').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {
                $('div#fadersolutions').fadeIn(500, function() {
                 $('div#fadersolutions').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {
                  $('div#faderwebsites').fadeIn(500, function() {
                   $('div#faderwebsites').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {

                       // Animation complete
                   });
                  });
                 });
                });
               });
              });
             });
            });
           });
          });
         });
        });
       });
      });
     });
    });
   });
  });
 });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to make a time intersection between all the fade animations, i.e before 500 milliseconds of the fadOut effect, the fadeIn effect starts.

I was searching for a function that works inversely like .delay() but couldn't find one, any ideas?

### Update

I did it this way:

```
var delay = 500;
var fadein = 1000;
var fadeout = 1000;
var intersection = 900;



$('div#faderhome').fadeIn(fadein, function() {
$('div#faderhome').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout);
$('div#faderbranding').delay( intersection ).fadeIn(fadein, function() {
$('div#faderbranding').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout);
$('div#faderbusiness').delay( intersection ).fadeIn(fadein, function() {
$('div#faderbusiness').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout);
$('div#fadercontact').delay( intersection ).fadeIn(fadein, function() {
$('div#fadercontact').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout);
$('div#fadermarketing').delay( intersection ).fadeIn(fadein, function() {
$('div#fadermarketing').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout);
$('div#faderprofile').delay( intersection ).fadeIn(fadein, function() {
$('div#faderprofile').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout);
$('div#fadersoftware').delay( intersection ).fadeIn(fadein, function() {
$('div#fadersoftware').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout);
$('div#faderidentity').delay( intersection ).fadeIn(fadein, function() {
$('div#faderidentity').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout);
$('div#fadersolutions').delay( intersection ).fadeIn(fadein, function() {
$('div#fadersolutions').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout);
$('div#faderwebsites').delay( intersection ).fadeIn(fadein, function() {
$('div#faderwebsites').delay( delay ).fadeOut(fadeout, function() {


        // Animation complete


});});});});});});});});});});});
```

This way I'm having an intersection of 100ms between the fadeIn and fadeOut animations, thanks to @T.J. Crowder

Comment: ***.....yikes.....***

Comment: +1 for properly formatting the code in this question.

Comment: Are you making a splash page by any chance? I for one welcome pages with a ten second animation.

Comment: @kingjiv now there are scrollbars :(

Comment: @caspar but now you can see what it's actually doing... and appreciate the epic nesting.

Comment: feel sorry for you having to type it all up, :)

Comment: @Val :) I'm still learning, now I'm looking for how to make an array.

Comment: @Mohamed: I've done an example of the array approach for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're trying to overlap the animations (have one start before the previous one finishes), rather that using the completion callback on the previous animation (which is usually the right thing, but not in this case), just use `delay` with a slightly shorter timeout than the `fadeOut`. E.g.:

```
$("#theFirstElement").fadeOut(500);
$("#theNextElement").delay(400).fadeIn(500);
```

That way, the `fadeIn` will overlap with the `fadeOut` by 100ms or so.

---

**Off-topic** (slightly): Since you're going to be changing that code *anyway*, I'd strongly recommend refactoring it a bit. Put the things you plan to animate in an array and then loop over the array.

<s>Completely untested,</s>  but I think it ends up looking like this:

```
var elements = [
        $('div#faderhome'),
        $('div#faderbranding'),
        $('div#faderbusiness'),
        $('div#fadercontact'),
        $('div#fadermarketing'),
        $('div#faderprofile'),
        $('div#fadersoftware'),
        $('div#faderidentity'),
        $('div#fadersolutions'),
        $('div#faderwebsites')
    ],
    index,
    fadeInTime = 500,
    fadeOutTime = 500,
    overlap = 100;

for (index = 0; index < elements.length; ++index) {
    elements[index]
        .delay(index === 0 ? 0 : (index * (fadeInTime + fadeOutTime)) - overlap)
        .fadeIn(fadeInTime)
        .delay(fadeInTime)
        .fadeOut(fadeOutTime);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/avetor)

As you can see, first I create an array of the elements to animate, then set up some variables (constants, really) for the fade in time, fade out time, and overlap, and then loop through the array using increasingly-long delays on the beginning of the animation (by multiplying the times by the index variable).

Comment: Well actually I'm still a beginner in jquery and java script, I'll search for that array thing if it's gonna make a smaller and more efficient code.

Comment: @Mohamed: No worries. Didn't really mean to write the code for you, but that's kind of how it turned out. More to show how you can loop through things, set up delay times, etc. Best,

Answer (score 0):

Give each div a class e.g.  `my_class`

http://jsfiddle.net/uQ2rv/

**CODE**

```
var all = $('div.my_class');
var release = false;
function fader(i){
    if(i==all.length) return false;//so it don't go on and on ... or use the animation complete here :)
    $(all.eq(i)).fadeIn(500, function() {
        $(all.eq(i)).fadeOut(500,function (){
             i++;
             fader(i);
        });
    });

}
fader(0);
```